# What happens to deleted texts on iCloud?

Tags: iphone, icloud, text

If i deleted a text from my phone and then backed it up to iCloud, is that text now deleted from iCloud?

Comment: What do you mean be "deleted from iCloud"? Not part of an iCloud backup any longer or something else?

Answer (score -1):

I want to tell you that the text is deleted from iCloud. 
First, if your iPhone is charging, using wifi and iCloud has enough space for your iPhone to back up the text, the text would had been backed up. And then you set the manual backup, so the text data has been overwritten by new data.